# git not pushing to remote after creating a new branch

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket

My git somehow got messed up. The problem has two stages:

1) I created a branch called perf_test, made some changes. I wanted to keep the changes in the new branch, but revert to master to check how things were. On master, I found that the changes on perf_test were showing up in the git status of master.

```
> git checkout -b perf_test
> touch /path/to/foo.txt
> git status
Uncommitted changes
modified /path/to/foo.txt
> git checkout master
> git status
Uncommitted changes
modified /path/to/foo.txt
```

I don't understand why these changes are showing up in master after switching to master.

2) I then undid all changes in perf_test, and went on to make some other changes in perf_test (this was not intended - I thought I was in master but was in perf_test - but that is not important)

```
> git checkout perf_test
> git rm /path/to/foo.txt
> git status
...clean...
> touch /path/to/bar.txt
> git commit -am "changed bar.txt"
...committed...
> git branch
...
*perf_test
...
> git checkout master
> git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
> git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date
```

I expect that the change to bar.txt must be pushed to origin and to heroku - but both are reporting that they are uptodate when I know that they are not (the changes never got pushed to either remote).

I want to push the bar.txt change to my remotes - how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your first list of commands, you never committed to any branch, so what you were seeing in `git status` output was the difference between the current commit (`HEAD`) and the working directory.  When you switch branches with `git checkout`, git tries to avoid doing anything to outstanding changes in the working directory.  Plus, since you hadn't committed anything to `perf_test` after creating it from `master`, `perf_test` was still identical to `master`, so it's not surprising that you'd see the same results while on `perf_test` as while on `master`.
2. I assume you typed `touch /path/to/bar.txt`, not `git touch`, but OK.  You made a change to `bar.txt` and commited that change to the `perf_test` branch, but then you pushed `master` (which was unchanged and didn't contain your updated `bar.txt`) to origin and heroku. Did you want to push your local branch `perf_test` to the remote branch `master`?  If so, the syntax is `git push origin perf_test:master` (and similarly for `heroku`).

Comment: Got it on 1. Yes, it was touch, not git touch - will fix. And that helps - what I want to do is to merge the change to bar.txt from perf_test into master, and then commit master, and push from master. I think it shd work, as described. Thanks!

Comment: OK, in that case, all you're missing is `git merge perf_test` after the `git checkout master` line. You don't need to commit to master after that, because the `git merge` command creates the merge commit for you (unless there's a merge conflict).

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful!